# In CFS group schedule, how can I know a sched_entity is a leaf one ( associated with a real task)?

Tags: linux, schedule

So the sched_entity will be associated with a real task if it is a leaf one in trees of cfs_rq. Otherwise, it will be a group scheduling entity that is not directly associated with any real task(Right?So this means task_of(se) is meaningless?).

My question is: given a sched_entity, how can we know it is a leaf one and associated with a real task_struct? Thanks

Comment: Or given a cfs_rq, how can we know it is a leaf cfs_rq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the macro: entity_is_task(se)

Answer (score 1):

Each non-leaf entity owns a "container" (it's a RB-tree in fact) which contains the `sched_entity(s)` in next level task group (it's sched_entity.my_q exactly), except the `sched_entity(s)` which are associated with the real threads. And that's how `entity_is_task()` works.